# postdetail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post'

Tags: python, django

I have have error in django/python.
I get this error when I enter the post list and try to open the post details:

postdetail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post'

when i try

views.py codes:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls.base import reverse
from django.urls.converters import SlugConverter
from .models import post

def index(request):
    tpost = post.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to the django website")

def postlist(request):
    tpost = post.objects.filter(status = "published")
    return render(request, "blog/post/list.html", {"posts": tpost})

def postdetail(request, npost, pk):
    post = get_list_or_404(npost, slug = npost, id = pk)

    return render(request, "blog/post/detail.html", {"fpost": post})
```

models.py Codes:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("draft", "Draft"),
        ("published", "Published"),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique_for_date = "publish")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "blog_post")
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = "draft")
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-publish",)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", args = [self.slug, self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and this is urls.py codes:

```
app_name = "blog"
urlpatterns = [
    path("postlist/", views.postlist, name = "post_list"),
    path("postdetail/<slug:post>/<int:pk>/", views.postdetail, name 
= "post_detail"),

]
```

Comment: Add your urls.py to the question. `postdetail` expects `npost` and `pk`, you may have misspelled one of the url parameters

Comment: You name the slug parameter in the url/path "post" but in the view it's named "npost"?

Comment: I change the names but i have new error:

    First argument to get_list_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'str'

Comment: The first argument to `get_list_or_404` should be your post model not the slug parameter

Comment: Can you explain more to me?

Comment: Pass `post` not `npost` as the first argument `get_list_or_404(post, slug=npost, id=pk)`. BTW, you should really use camel-case for your models/classes to differentiate them from regular variables: name your model `Post`

Comment: you're right. I chose the model name and variables incorrectly.
And my problem was solved.
Thank you.